# Webcrawler multiple page iteration

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I want to make the crawler go to the next page to extract data any help on what to do. I am a little lost on what to do. I tried scrapy but it is kinda complicated and bs4 is more convenient.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import re


source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://messageboards.webmd.com/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')


df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['link'],data=[url.a.get('href') for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link")])
lists=[]

for i in range(0,33):
    link = (df.link.iloc[i])
    source1 = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
    soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(source1,'lxml')
    for url1 in soup1.find_all('a',class_="next"):
        next_link = soup1.find('a',href = True, text = re.compile("next"))
        if next_link:
            lists.append(link+url1.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you're storing hrefs in a list

```
for url1 in soup1.find_all('a',class_="next"):
    next_link = soup1.find('a',href = True, text = re.compile("next"))
    if next_link:
        lists.append(link+url1.get('href'))
```

Now you actually have to do something with them. In this case I'm assuming you want to navigate to each href in your list.

```
for href in lists:
   new_page = urllib.request.urlopen(href).read()
```

And then you can scrape whatever data you want out of new_page

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. Here is my code example for a page I crawled for exercise. I've chained multiple site requests to get detailed information.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from capterra.items import CapterraItem

class CapterraCatSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'capterra_cat'
    #allowed_domains = ['http://www.capterra.com/categories']
    start_urls = ['http://www.capterra.com/categories']
    # rules = (
    #     Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    # )

def parse(self, response):
    #TEMP
    for category in response.css('ol.browse-group-list'):
        #Debug: only elements of one category
        if category.css('a::text').extract_first() == 'Yoga Studio':
            i = CapterraItem()
            #Get link to detail page
            i['cat_name'] = category.css('a::text').extract_first()
            #join link to detail page with base url
            i['cat_link'] = response.urljoin(category.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first())

            cat_link = i['cat_link']
            print cat_link
            #call request to detail page and pass response to parse_details method with callback method
            request = scrapy.Request(cat_link, callback=self.parse_details)

            request.meta['item'] = i
            yield request

def parse_details(self,response):
    #Debug print
    print 'DETAILS!'
    #read your items from response meta
    item = response.meta['item']
    #iterate over listings
    for detail in response.css('p.listing-description.milli'):
        item['profile_link'] = response.urljoin(detail.css('a.spotlight-link::attr(href)').extract_first())
        #call request to profile page to get more information for listing
        request = scrapy.Request(item['profile_link'], callback=self.parse_profile)
        #set your item to rquest metadata
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

def parse_profile(self,response):
    #Debug print
    print 'PROFILE'
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['product_name'] = response.css('h1.beta.no-margin-bottom::text').extract_first()
    item['who_uses_software'] = response.css('div.spotlight-target > p.epsilon > i::text').extract_first()
    item['vendor_name'] = response.css('h2.spotlight-vendor-name > span::text').extract_first()

    return item
```